# How to remove subdirectory and index.php from URL with htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've got an apache website stored on the server at `/var/www/website/` and it's the only one on that server. I'd like to adjust the URL accordingly. How can I make an `.htaccess` rule that would do this?

**before**: `https://example.com/website/index.php`
**after**: `https://example.com/`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the `index.php` file into `/var/www/` directly?  If you do that, what you want automatically happens.   Alternately, you could edit your webserver config to set the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/website/` rather than `/var/www/`.    Both of those are simple changes that prevent a lot of ugliness in *.htaccess*

Comment: That's a workable method, and the end I did go with the DocumentRoot setting you suggested, but nevertheless I had the question about how to do it with .htaccess and would still like to learn that method, even if only for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of information here. For instance, what do you want to happen with all your other URLs (do you have any other URLs)? For the sake of this answer I assume you just have a single URL, `/` that needs to rewrite to `/website/index.php` (as stated in your question).

Anyway, you don't do this entirely in `.htaccess`. The first thing you must do is:

1. Change the URL in your application. Change your links to point to `https://example.com/` (not `https://example.com/website/index.php`)
2. You can then use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to internally rewrite the URL from `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/website/index.php` (the underlying filesystem path):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Rewrite "/" to "/website/index.php"
   RewriteRule ^$ /website/index.php [L]
   ```
3. Optionally, if you are changing an existing URL structure and you need to preserve SEO then you can also implement an external redirect from `/website/index.php` to `/`. However, you must **only do this if you have implemented step #1 above**. This goes *before* the above rewrite:

   ```
   # Redirect "/website/index.php" to "/"
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteRule ^website/index\.php$ / [R=302,L]
   ```

   The `RewriteCond` (condition) is necessarily to prevent a redirect loop. To prevent the rewritten URL (above) being redirected.

   (Change to a 301 only after you have tested that this works OK - to avoid caching issues whilst testing.)

### In Summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/website/index.php" to "/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^website/index\.php$ / [R=302,L]

# Rewrite "/" to "/website/index.php"
RewriteRule ^$ /website/index.php [L]
```